# What is the best way to create suspendable/resumable threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I am doing some network programming for a microprocessor which sends low buffer notifications and I have a thread that writes a set amount of information. When it is done it needs to enter a suspended state and wait for the low buffer notification to resume.

Is it better to use windows' thread pool api, or to use threads that are created with `CreateThread()`?

Comment: You need to add a windows tag. Also, I suspect that you are writing a Windows driver, not a regular program? If so you must tell us, it is a very different environment.

Comment: I added the windows tag. I dont think its technically a windows driver as it only uses TCP and UDP network programming, and aside from reliable thread control I have everything else working.

If interested, the device I am programming for is the ether-dream: http://www.ether-dream.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your thread needs to wait, it should begin waiting on an event. This suspends the thread automatically.

Windows provides the WaitForMultipleObjects and WaitForSingleObject functions for this. Linux uses condition variables or semaphores.

Comment: What if you need to suspend a different thread? This approach doesnt work.

Comment: @chacham15: Don't design your code so that you need to suspend other threads. You set an event/condition/variable and the other thread checks it and suspends itself, waiting for something to happen.

Comment: Here's an example, what if i'm writing an application which manages cpu usage. I want to be able to suspend threads which are hogging the cpu in favor of threads belonging to a program which the user cares about. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Either remove the app that is hogging the CPU or reduce its priority?  Communication between low-level drivers and threads/s that manage them is usually performed by signaling semaphores - on many OS, the the lowest level interrupt handlers are not allowed to do much else.  Don't go near explicit suspend/resume control.  I know it's kinda nice and easy if you could just say 'stop' to a manager thread and be sure it isn't maniplulating buffer pointers etc. so that you can, but I'm afraid driver coders don't get this kind of luxury.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create a suspendable thread is:

```
std::thread thread(function, arguments);
```

When you want to suspend the execution of that thread at a later stage you can use the `wait()` member of `std::condition_variable` or `std::condition_variable_any`.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use single threads created with CreateThread. ThreadPool threads are meant to do simple tasks and then return to the pool, they are not meant for long running tasks, waits or I/O operations. This is because they are limited in number and once you have one running and waiting, you cannot use it somewhere else.

Furthermore, ThreadPool threads are managed by the system and are not meant to be identifiable from the outside. You're better off using classic Threads.